# Why do register arg values need to be re-assigned in NASM after an int 0x80 system call?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

So I'm still learning NASM assembly, I'm far from knowledgeable, which you can probably tell from this literal hello world program, but I'm curious about an issue. When I run:

```
section .text:
    global _start

_start:
    mov edx, len
    mov ecx, msg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    mov edx, len2
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

section .data:
    msg db "Let's test this thing!"
    len equ $ - msg
    msg2 db "This is the second line."
    len2 equ $ - msg2
```

If I omit the second `mov eax, 4` and `mov ebx, 1`, it prints the first line, but not the second line.

When I do re-assign `ebx` and `eax` before running the second one, to the same values as originally, works fine and prints both lines.  (This is the version in the code block.)

I don't really understand why this is the case - the registers have already been set and I haven't changed them, so why do I need to re-assign them to the same values that they should already have before running the interrupt again? I'd love some help, because this really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `eax` is the return value from the system call. See also [man 2 write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). `ebx` should not need to be reloaded as that does not change.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, that works, when I run it only resetting `eax` it works, I think that makes sense. Much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) which says that all regs except EAX are preserved by `int 0x80`. (And I think links the ABI doc to back that up, which has a section on Linux system calls)  Despite the title, *not* a duplicate of [Does int 0x80 overwrite register values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17870031) which is about `int 0x80` in 64-bit mode (which you normally shouldn't do).

Comment: Also related: [What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38751614)